# Join collections on a specific value in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections in MongoDB testA and testB. They are related by a traditional one to many relationship. One member of testA can be associated with many elements of testB.

```
> db.testA.find({}).pretty()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60508eeb52a2ab598a013bb9") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60508f2852a2ab598a013bba") }

> db.testB.find({}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60508f4152a2ab598a013bbb"),
    "aId" : ObjectId("60508f2852a2ab598a013bba")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60508f4552a2ab598a013bbc"),
    "aId" : ObjectId("60508f2852a2ab598a013bba")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("605090a452a2ab598a013bbd"),
    "aId" : ObjectId("60508eeb52a2ab598a013bb9")
}
```

Now I want to query for the document in `testA` that corresponds to a specific it in `testB`.

In SQL this would be something like: "select * from testB join testA where testB._id = 605090a452a2ab598a013bbd". This would return the document corresponding to `60508eeb52a2ab598a013bb9`.

How do I do this in MongoDB syntax?

Comment: A `$match`, [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation…?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right, I am new to MongoDB so I'm not yet familiar with building it up.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you will join the two collection based on their relation id
ref: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

```
db.testA.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "testB",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "aId",
      "as": "join"
    }
  }
])
```

Mongo Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/L5eOQ9zU-y6

if you want to join by particular id then

```
db.testA.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: ObjectId("60508eeb52a2ab598a013bb9")
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "testB",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "aId",
      "as": "join"
    }
  }
])
```

Mongo Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/fOnt2-NZTJ7